# How to transform and pivot in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like following

I'd like to count each product and transform them

`t1`

```
customer product
A            a
A            b
A            c 
B            a
B            c
C            a
```

My desired result is following,

```
customer  product(a) product(b) product(c)
A           1           1           1
B           1           0           1
C           1           0           0
```

Are there any way to transform ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `conditional aggregation`

```
select customer,count(case when product='a' then 1 end) as product_a,
count(case when product='b' then 1 end) as product_b,
count(case when product='c' then 1 end) as product_c
from tablename
group by customer
```

Another option could be using the `pivot operator` -

```
SELECT * FROM t
 PIVOT (count(product) FOR product IN 
    ( 'a' AS product_a, 'b' AS  product_b, 'c' AS product_c ))
```

Comment: Thanks can I select row as `customer` in `pivot` ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Still One more Conditional Aggregation Method which is manipulated through use of traditional [DECODE()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm) function spesific to Oracle DB exists. In which values of ones summed up if product matches with the literals(`'a'`,`'b'` or `'c'`), otherwise(`else` case) zeroes return :

```
SELECT customer,
       SUM(DECODE(product , 'a', 1, 0 )) AS product_a,
       SUM(DECODE(product , 'b', 1, 0 )) AS product_b,
       SUM(DECODE(product , 'c', 1, 0 )) AS product_c
  FROM t
 GROUP BY customer
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ea5b3a1a750fe05b22525f3553b4d672)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bcda68/2)

```
select * from table1 
pivot(count(product) 
      for product 
      in ('a' "product(a)", 'b' "product(b)", 'c' "product(c)", 'd' "product(d)"));
```